# How can I create a list with hyperlinks to files in my website automatically?

Tags: html, directory-listing

I'm a total newbie creating a website as a
school project.

If in my website I have a number of documents in HTML format inside a folder and want to create a list with hyperlinks to those documents (so that a user can click and access the document), which can be updated easily without having to edit it manually to add new documents, how would I do it? 
Is there some HTML code I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Apache as your webserver, you can use the `Options +Indexes` directive in a `.htaccess` file to enable a simple file listing within a directory *if* no `index.html` (or other index file, as determined by the `DirectoryIndex` directive) exists.

**Note:** `AllowOverride all` must be set in your Apache configuration to support use of `.htaccess` directives - it's a common hosting configuration so this shouldn't be an issue, however, you may want to follow up with your hosting provider if directory indexes are not working or you are unsure whether Apache is being used to host your site.

Comment: Thank for the answer. I don't know yet whether Apache is used, since I'm still at the stage of creating the files on my hard disk before uploading them. Could I install Apache on my Debian system and try this offline? Also, If I use the Options +Indexes you suggest, would I be able to determinate the style the index appears on the webpage?

Comment: Apache2 is just a `sudo apt install apache2` away on Debian. You can style the index pages - here's an [Apache directory themes](https://github.com/ramlmn/Apache-Directory-Listing) project at GitHub to get started with examples (but do check with your hosting provider before getting too deep into Apache-specific implementation - you need Apache + `AllowOverride all` to make this work).